# How to convert Image RAW10 format to cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to convert Image [RAW10](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#RAW10) to cv::Mat. But in the finish, I have always gray square. The conversation I make like:

```
void ConvertToMat(unsigned char * buffer, unsigned int width, unsigned int height) {
    cv::Mat img;
    cv::Mat raw(height, width, CV_8UC1, buffer);
    raw.convertTo(img, CV_32FC1, 255.0); // -> don't work
    cv::imwrite("myimage.png", img);

    cv::cvtColor(raw, raw, cv::COLOR_BayerGR2RGBA); //-> also don't work
    cv::imwrite("myimage.png", raw);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specification of your 10 bit data format? Probably you will need bitshift operations to extract the meaningful per-pixel data and embedd it in 16 bit pixel data.

Comment: yeah, what's in the buffer? why do you _multiply_ by 255?

Comment: buffer - it is raw data (image from camera). https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#RAW10